# Unit Test with CSRF token

Tags: php, phpunit, csrf, fuelphp

How can i set csrf_token via [curl request].(http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/request/curl.html)

im filtering my token via

```
class Controller_Core extends \Controller_Rest
{
    public function router($method, $params)
    {
        $token       = \Security::check_token();
        $method_type = \Request::main()->get_method();

        if ($token || $method_type === 'GET'){
            // call the REST router to process the request
            return parent::router($method, $params);
        }

        // validation failed, return a HTTP 401 and a message
        $rsp = ['error' => 'Not Authorized'];
        $this->response($rsp, 401);
    }
}
```

have tried

```
/**
 * @group Login
 */
class Test_Classes_Controller_Account_LoginTest extends \TestCase {

    /**
     * @covers Controller_Account_Login::post_index
     */
    public function testLoginToken () {
        $res = \Request::forge('/api/account/login/security_token.json')
                ->set_method('GET')
                ->execute()
                ->response();

        return \Security::fetch_token();
    }

    /**
     * @group Login
     * @depends testLoginToken
     */
    public function testLoginFailIncoCred ($token) {
        $_POST['csrf_token'] = $token;

        $curl = \Request::forge(\Uri::create('api/account/login.json'), 'curl')
                    ->set_method('POST')
                    ->set_params(array(
                        'email' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ))
                    ->execute()
                    ->response();

        var_dump($curl);
    }

}
```

i also tried putting the `csrf_token` via header-cookie, $_POST params and as curl params but still no luck

How can i make a request that will dynamically set/retrieve the csrf_token from the server ?

I can disable the csrf security for test environment, but i think that is not the best practice for the test.

Any Suggestions/Comments/Repo will be appreciated

Comment: It is a  functional test. You need to make 2 curl requests - first retrieve the form with the token, then submit the form with the token.

Comment: i also posted this question on the [fuelphp forums](http://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/comment/20860#Comment_20860)